# Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.lang.module.FindException: Module org.slf4j not found, required by org.apache.poi.ooxml

Tags: java

This is my first question in StackOverflow. I was trying to write the Excel File in the eclipse environment and I am getting this error . I have added all the external jars of apachePOI in Modulepath. I have tried it adding in Classpath but there was an error due to that. I only have a single class in the entire package. Please help resolve this.
[This is the screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGui4.png)

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
package utilities_new;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
```

public class WriteExcelFile {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Blank Workbook
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    
    ////Create Excel Sheet
    XSSFSheet samplesheet = workbook.createSheet("SampleSheet");
    
    //Creating the data
    Map<String, Object[]> dataset = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
    dataset.put("1", new Object[] {"ID","NAME","COMPANY"});
    dataset.put("2", new Object[] {"1", "Karthik", "Eclipse"});
    dataset.put("3", new Object[] {"2", "Shaina", "Twitter"});
    dataset.put("4", new Object[] {"3", "Naruto", "Hidden Leaf"});
    dataset.put("5", new Object[] {"4", "Jiraiya", "Google"});
    dataset.put("6", new Object[] {"5", "Tsunade", "Facebook"});
    
    //Iterating over data
    Set<String> set = dataset.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for(String key: set) {
        Row row = samplesheet.createRow(rownum++);
        
        Object[] data = dataset.get(key);
        int cellnum = 0;
        
        for(Object value: data) {
            
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
            
            if(value instanceof String)
                cell.setCellValue((String) value);
            else if(value instanceof Integer)
                cell.setCellValue((Integer)value);  
        }
    }
    //Write down the file on Disk.
    try {
        FileOutputStream writefile = new 
        FileOutputStream("sampleTest.xlsx");
        workbook.write(writefile);
        
        writefile.close();
        System.out.println("Sample excel file has been created 
         successfully!!!!");
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
         }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
         }  
}
```

}

Comment: Please add WriteExcelFile.java content(codes) as plaint text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.